# Relations by marriage after the married person dies

Tags: kinship-terms

Let's say Alice is married to Bob. Alice died. Is Alice's mother still referred to as Bob's mother-in-law? Let's say Alice also had a brother Charlie. Is Bob still referred to as the uncle of Charlie's children?

In other words: does the title survive the death of the family member whose marriage created the relationship in the first place?

Edit to add: I just want to add that individual families will do whatever they feel is right based on their situation. I'm asking about the technical definition.

Comment: related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17978/how-are-relative-familial-titles-used-for-members-who-died-prior-to-your-birth

Comment: we need a genealogy forum

Comment: Yes, titles survive death. In most cases, they even survive divorce (I still call my uncle's ex-wife my aunt, and my grandmother always considered her a daughter-in-law, even if the law no longer did).

Comment: The question is answered in Stack Exchange/Genealogy & Family History --->https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9253/what-is-relationship-of-widower-to-late-wifes-family-i-e-in-laws

Comment: @lbf - Do you mean one like [genealogy.se]?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin lol yes!